# CentOS Stream - dotnet app works on root but is killed on regular user

Tags: centos, ulimit

I have a **dotnet** application. It requires quite a lot of memory. Everything worked on CentOS 8, but on a fresh CentOS Stream installation weird things are happening...

If I run that all as regular user it gets killed after RES parameter in TOP command reaches ~250k. Every thing works fine if I run the same App as root.

Here is the TOP stats for App running as root.

```
    Tasks: 28 total, 1 running, 27 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie

%Cpu(s): 0.5 us, 1.0 sy, 0.0 ni, 98.5 id, 0.0 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.0 si, 0.0 st

MiB Mem : 2048.0 total, 793.4 free, 959.0 used, 295.5 buff/cache

MiB Swap: 512.0 total, 508.1 free, 3.9 used. 1089.0 avail Mem


PID USER PR NI VIRT RES SHR S %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND

146 root 20 0 261.5g 1.0g 149760 S 1.7 50.1 8:16.68 dotnet
```

I played with **ulimit** (and /etc/security/limit.conf) config for regular user but no success.

Any ideas what other settings should I configure?